# Access all values in the list in Python

Tags: python, list, flask

How do I access and print all values from a list using Python? Here is my code which I run in `flask.` I got only `www.google.com`; how do I access all the values?

The code:

```
domain = ["www.google.com","www.facebook.com"]
@app.route('/')
def users():
  for row in domain:
    return str(row)
```

The output:

[image: This is the output]

Comment: return the list i.e `def users(): return domain`

Comment: but the issue is i have to do some functions with each domains like ipwhois??

Comment: @Wasi, but that would simply give them what they already have, the list `domain`.

Comment: @Shan we need to see more of what you are trying to do to help you with using each domain. Do you mean that you want to get the first one, give it to something else, then get the second one and give it to that something else, too?

Comment: actually i have to use ipwhois library to get some details in each links. but i get return only from one domain when i use for loop inside the function

Comment: So can you give us an example of the larger code context, including where you would use this, and where you want to hand the link to whatever gives it to ipwhois?

Comment: You need to loop over the **domains** and do whatever you want, and return the result (list or dict) to your template and in the template loop over it again.

Answer (score 1):

You are returning the first value in the list. As soon as the code hit `return` it stops anything after that. You can either do `str(domain)`, which will give you the string representation of the whole list, or simply customize format the information in to **one** string and return it.

If you are making an API like project. Dump it into a json string is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

To `print` all the items in the list, do:

```
domain = ["www.google.com","www.facebook.com"]
def users(list):
  for row in list:
    print(row)
```

And then:

```
users(domain)
```

You code begins to do something like this, but as soon as you `return` `str(row)`, or anything for that matter, the function returns what it has so far and exits. That's what `return` implies. If `return` was speaking to you in English, here's what it would say, on behalf of the function that contains it:

> "I'm done now. Here's what I did: `returned value`."

If your Question means something more than `print` the items, please edit the Question to show more of the code that includes this, so we have a better understanding of how to answer, and what you are actually trying to do.

For example, we have no idea what app.route is, is for, or is intended to do, and it doesn't have any apparent relevance in the code snippet included in your Question.

Happy New Year!